# On hover and click I want to add border around my color box, how do I do that?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I want to be able to create a border around the image color that I have `onclick` so the user knows that they have clicked on it. How do I do that?

[image: Color box 1]

This is how I want it to be as you can see there is border around it `onselect` and it stays on.

[image: Color box 2]

```
.text-image-list-image {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px;  
}

.text-image-list-title {
  margin-bottom: 6px !important;
}



  return (
    <div>
      <Title name={name} />
      {content.map(({ src, content, value }, index) => (
        <div key={index} style={{ display: "inline-block", cursor: "pointer"}} onClick={ () => setCurrentSelection(value)}>
          <p>{content}</p>
          <a><img className="text-image-list-image" src={src} alt="" /></a>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: I think you should use outline instead of border.

Comment: `onClick` add a class with a border to the clicked item.

Comment: Are they able to select more than one color at once or does clicking another color unselect the previously selected one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it via a new class like so.

```
<div className={currentSelection === value ? "with_border" : "no_border"} key={index} style={{ display: "inline-block", cursor: "pointer"}} onClick={ () => setCurrentSelection(value)}.....
```

Your css class would be something like

```
.with_border{
   border: 2px solid grey;
}
```

Comment: forgot to close the className brace after `"no_border"`

Comment: @NikitaSkrebets Good spot damn copy paste!! xD